# Colocar uma condição em uma função exportada no node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, funções, electron

Estou com uma dúvida pertinente, estou começando um projeto em electron onde tenho que fazer a conexão com dois bancos diferentes, um local e outro em nuvens, no meu código node js, tenho dois arquivos o index.js onde coloco os dados referentes ao electron e outro database.js onde vou chamar o banco de dados, daí vem a dúvida, quando utilizo o module.exports = function ..., para exportar a função para o index.js, não consigo utilizar esta função esportada para fazer uma condição if onde dependendo da resposta do primeira sql devo executar a segunda em um outro banco, segue o código para entender melhor

> database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
module.exports = function execSQLbd(sqlQry){  
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      port     : 3306,
      user     : 'teste',
      password : 'teste',
      database : 'teste'
  });
  connection.connect(function(err) {
      // in case of error
      if(err){
          console.log(err.code);
          console.log(err.fatal);
      }
  });
  connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, rows, fields){
      if(error){
          console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
          console.log(err);
          return;
      }
      
      nome = rows[0].nome;
      id = rows[0].id;
      connection.end();

      return id;
      //console.log(id);
  }); 
}
```

> Quando mudo o return para console.log ele aparece o resultado do database, mas o problema é colocar este resultado no if, pois quando coloco a condição no index.js ele roda primeiro o if e depois a função do database;
> Desde já agradeço a quem poder colaborar...

> > index.js

```
var execSQLbd = require('./models/db1');
banco1 = new execSQLbd("SELECT * FROM pagamentos WHERE id = '1'");

if (banco1 == 1)
 return true;


const {app, BrowserWindow} = require ('electron');


let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () =>{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({

    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/teste.html`)
});
```

Comment: Pq vc está utilizando `new` pra invocar uma função? (`new execSQLbd()`)

Comment: Independente se usar o new, não consigo retornar o valor para usar em um if;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Alan Juan me ajudou bastante,
Estudei mais sobre Promise e async,
Optei em importar apenas variaveis do arquivo db, assim fica mais fácil de entender o código;
No Código abaixo fiz uma readaptação o que funcionou perfeitamente;

> > index.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require ('electron');
const conc = require('./models/db1');

function select(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conc.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            id = rows[0].id;
            resolve(id);
        });
    });
}
    async function SqlResponde (codigo) {
        const result = await select(codigo);
        if(result == 2)
        console.log("Deu Certo");
        else  
        console.log("Deu Errado"); 

        console.log(result);        
        //return result;        
    }
  
SqlResponde("SELECT * FROM pagamentos WHERE id = '1'");

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () =>{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
});

mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/teste.html`);
});
```

> > db1.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '',
      port     : 3306,
      user     : '',
      password : '',
      database : ''
  });
  connection.connect(function(err) {
      // in case of error
      if(err){
          console.log(err.code);
          console.log(err.fatal);
      }
  });

module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

O `new` só deve ser utilizado para instanciar objetos de uma classe, não para invocar funções. No mais, esse problema se deve ao fato de você estar realizando uma operação assíncrona (uma consulta ao banco de dados) sem sinalizar ao `Node.js` que ele deve esperar para que ela complete.

```js
const execSQLbd = require('./models/db1');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require ('electron');

async (() => {
    // Utilizando esse await, o fluxo só segue quando o resultado de execSQLbd
    // estiver pronto. Sem ele, o fluxo alcança o if antes que a função termine
    const banco1 = await execSQLbd("SELECT * FROM pagamentos WHERE id = '1'");

    if (banco1 == 1)
        return true;

    let mainWindow;

    app.on('ready', () =>{
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/teste.html`)
});
```

No mais, recomendo a você que evite o uso de `var`, em virtude do hoisting, que pode causar efeitos indesejados. Recomendo as leituras:

https://javascript.info/var

https://javascript.info/async-await